# Setting frames datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

My WPF window should be able to load in different controls in same spot on the window; which should be frames to fulfill that task.

Hence i'm trying to make a frame load different pages by editing a databound string containing the Frames source. And I have managed to do that, however at the moment I have no idea how to share the frames data to the windows viewmodel hosting the frame.

---

I'm using MVVM and I thougth that if I could also databind a "viewmodel" to the frames datacontext, I could then both choose which page to load and which datacontext the page should use, all from the host window, therefore having access to it.

Below is my xaml.

```
<Window x:Class="View.Window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" DataContext="{Binding WindowClass.DataContext}" Source="{Binding WindowClass.FrameURI}"/>
</Grid>
```

However, if I now assign the pages datacontext through this binding, instead of in the code behind, nothing gets loaded. Now I basically end up with a blank frame.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Window.Resources` to bind to your `DataContext`, then Bind to the `FrameURI` (You'll need to fix the appropriate `namespace` instead of my custom `xmlns:WindowClass`):

```
<Window x:Class="View.Window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WindowClass="clr-namespace:WindowClass"
    Title="Window" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <WindowClass:MyViewModelName/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" DataContext={Binding} Source="{Binding FrameURI}"/>
</Grid>
```

You can find a very basic tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute)

Comment: Well the issue is not databinding to the window. The problem lies in the frames "view" since it´s a childwindow, the main window must provide datacontext to the frame to be able to access its view model. Im basically trying to share data between "two windows" however one of the windows happens to be hosted inside the other window, and it is hosted in it as a container, just like anyother WPF element would.

Comment: Try setting `DataContext={Binding}`

Comment: DataContext="{Binding}" did not work for me.